# Change value in yaml file without changing the files structure

Tags: jenkins, yaml, kubernetes-helm, gitops

I'm thinking about setting up a GitOps CI/CD pipeline in my cluster with Jenkins and ArgoCD.

For a start I want to have a repository for my CI environment with some values files for the Helm charts of my applications.

One thing that I cannot really figure out is, how I can automatically edit the Helm values files without changing the whole structure of the files.

The Jenkins pipeline methods for reading and writing yaml files will fully recreate it and in the process re-format the whole file.

`yq` does not (seem to) re-order the keys, but it removes empty lines and comments, for example.

Only other thing that comes to my mind is using `sed`. But that feels kind-of wrong. And it might easily break. Like when I add a second key in another group with the same name. Or add a or remove keys.

Here's an example, to make it a bit more clear:

I have two repositories, one for my application, one for my CI, NI, ... configuration.

My application repo is not that important. Just some application. My config repository looks somewhat like this:

```
 .
...
├── ci
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── values.yaml
│   ├── app2
...
├── staging
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── Chart.yaml
│   │   ├── values.yaml
│   ├── app2
...
```

The `values.yaml` file of `app1` in the `ci` folder might look like this:

```yaml
app1:
  image:
    tag: 1.33.7

  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
      - app1.my-internal-ci.company.com
  ...
```

The actual helm charts are somewhere else and here is only the configuration for the the applications on the environments.

ArgoCD watches this repo and takes care that the desired state (as specified by the state of the repo) and the actual state in the cluster match (see https://argoproj.github.io/cd/ for more on the tool).

As a last step my CI pipeline for `app1`, that builds a docker image from the code in my application repo, should update the `values.yaml` file in the `ci` folder in the configuration repo with the new version `1.33.8` of the application that was just build and push it as a new commit to the main branch.

Besides that, there are other values configured, like the ingress for example, that I update manually in the repo, if needed.

Since the files are updated automatically by the CI build pipeline and manually by a developer / DevOps engineer, I would like to be able to keep them easily readable by a human (order of the keys, newlines, comments, ...)

Is there any other way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish? Why are you editing the value files? Can you just use *different* value files in CI? This question would be better with a specific example.

Comment: I added an example to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some further digging I think the best option I have right now is `yq`. In newer versions (> 3.0.0; https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/19) it should not remove any comments anymore. And with the newline-thing I can live, I think.

So if you have the files as mentioned above you could update your image tag with:

```sh
yq -i '.app1.image.tag = "1.33.8"' ci/app1/values.yaml
```

Worth mentioning: If you're using kustomize instead of Helm, there is a built-in for this: `kustomize edit set image my-app=myregistry.io/my-platform/my-app:1.2.3`.

Thanks for your ideas and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You can straightforwardly use the `helm install -f` option here.  There are two important details about it:

1. The `helm install -f` values are used in addition to the `values.yaml` in the chart.  You do not need to repeat the chart's values in your local settings.
2. `helm install -f` takes any valid YAML file; but every valid JSON file is a valid YAML file, so if your CI tool can write out JSON, it can create a file that can be passed to `helm install -f`.

Indeed, the precise format of the YAML file doesn't really matter, so long as the right keys and sequences and mappings are there with the right structure.

In a Jenkins context, you can use the standard [`writeJSON`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writejson-write-json-to-a-file-in-the-workspace) function to produce a local values file:

```
// Only need to provide the specific values we need to set;
// the chart's values.yaml will be used for anything we don't
// directly provide here
helmValues = ['environment': 'production',
              'tag': GIT_COMMIT]
writeJSON file: 'values.deploy.yaml', json: helmValues

sh 'helm upgrade --install -n myproject myproject ./charts/myproject -f values.deploy.yaml'
```

Comment: To add onto this, you can specify multiple `-f` in the command. The last one takes prescedence and overrides the others. For example: `helm install someChart -f base_values.yaml -f devEnvironment.yaml -f productionEnvironment.yaml`

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but it seems I did not explain my issue good enough. I don't want to execute helm upgrade from my CI pipeline, but rather use a CD tool (like ArgoCD) to do the actual deployment. I added an example to my original post to outline the setup I want to go for.